# Timeout of remote connection to Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, amazon-ec2

I have two EC2 instances, one of them needs to insert large amounts of data into a Postgresql db that lives on the other one. Incidentally it's Open Street Map data and I am using the `osm2pgsql` utility to insert the data, not sure if that's relevant, I don't think so.

For smaller inserts everything is fine but for very large inserts something times out after around 15 minutes and the operation fails with:

`COPY_END for planet_osm_point failed: SSL SYSCALL error: Connection timed out`

Is this timeout enforced by Postgresql, Ubuntu or AWS? Not too sure where to start troubleshooting.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Could be caused by renegotiation. Check the log, and maybe tweak
`ssl_renegotiation_limit = 512MB` (the default)
[setting it to zero will disable negotiation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/runtime-config-connection.html)

Comment: Thanks, so when you say check the log do you mean the ssl log or postgresql log? If ssl, would you look on the database server machine or the client machine that connects to it. Sorry, I'm pretty new at this stuff. Thanks again.

Comment: As of 2016, according to the docs, the default setting for ssl_renegotiation_limit is zero.  Still, you should check your settings to make sure. Also, this is still an issue :-/